# Can we fix the delay when bringing up the link dialog, please?

Tags: bug, documentation, hyperlinks, editor

This has bitten me a few times now. Ever since Documentation went into public beta, hitting Ctrl+L has been annoying. Before writing the link text in a post (normal Stack Overflow; not documentation), I usually have the link URL in my copy/paste buffer, so I habitually press Ctrl+L, Ctrl+V in quick succession.

That used to be fine - but now the dialog box has a pause as it opens (three dots pulsating), and I end up with the link URL overwriting the link text in the post, and no URL in the link dialog. Very annoying.

Even if the delay itself can't be reduced, I suspect the point at which the keyboard input ends up in the dialog instead of in the post text could be fixed.

(I've tagged this as "bug" rather than "feature request" as it's definitely a regression in functionality as far as I'm concerned.)

Browser: Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: This is still in normal Q/A posts, right? Would you mind sharing your browser because on Chrome I don't see that delay.

Comment: @rene: Yes, that's in normal Stack Overflow, using Chrome. It may be relevant that I'm currently on hotel wifi and have spent the last couple of weeks on a combination of hotel and mobile data... but I *think* I saw this at home too.

Comment: @rene: Have added a few clarifying details into the post.

Comment: There is a slightly bigger payload coming over the network on main every time that dialog is shown .  Is it correct that on meta you can't repro?

Comment: @rene while writing some post yesterday on meta, muscle memory was always faster than the modal.

Comment: Right now, it takes ~76 ms to load the dialog. Maybe Saturday morning is slow...

Comment: @Braiam: I can definitely repro on Meta as well. Ctrl+L, Ctrl+V puts the clipboard contents into the post instead of the dialog :(

Comment: Maybe you have bad latency. In the Developers Tools (F12), move to the network tab so the even gets recorded, open the dialog and look for the transfer called "insert-link". Look for the tab that says "timing", it should tell you how much time took to complete the transaction.

Comment: for me that says between 99ms and 175ms for 6 observations